# NGRX: http retry interceptor causing failure action not to be fired

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-httpclient

I am using NGRX and I want to have simple **GET** requests to an API to be **retried** five times. Reason for this is that I am using Azure Cosmos-DB and I am being throttled sometimes. (free-tier).

I've created an http-interceptor for this which is pretty straight forward and looks like that

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpRetryInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  public intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    httpHandler: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const nextRequest = request.clone();

    // here the NGRX failure action is not being triggered after five failing requests
    return httpHandler.handle(nextRequest).pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(5))),
      last()
    );
  }
}
```

This works just fine and each failing http-request is retried five times with a delay of 1000ms.

Problem now is, that the failure action in the effect is not being triggered when the requests actually failed for five times.

```
load$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(globalStatsActions.load),
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.globalStatsService.load().pipe(
        map(stats =>
          globalStatsActions.loaded({
            latestStats: stats
          })
        ),
        catchError(() => of(globalStatsActions.loadFailed())) // not being called using the http-interceptor
      )
    )
  )
);
```

What is weird is, that when the http-interceptor uses the operator `retry` rather than `retryWhen` it works just fine. Sadly, with that operator you cannot define a `delay`, which is required in my case.

Another interesting fact is, that when using the very same retry logic on the service used in the effect, it works just fine.

```
// here the failure action is being triggered after five failing requests
public load(): Observable<GlobalStats> {
  return this.http.get<GlobalStats>(`${this.baseUrl}stats`)
  .pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(5))),
    last()
  );
```

While this is not much code and could be copied onto each http-service that I am using, I would love to use an interceptor for it instead.

I couldn't seem to find the cause for that and I hope, that anyone out there knows why this is not working.

Comment: Is that the only interceptor you're using?

Comment: Yes, currently that's the only one.

Comment: And this is the `load()` method's body: `return this.http.get<GlobalStats>(`${this.baseUrl}stats`)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's a simple http-call , no pipe operator used there, plain http-get with `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Another interesting fact is, that when using the very same retry logic on the service used in the effect, it works just fine.

`retry(n)` will simply pass along the error notification when `n` attempts are reached. When attempts < `n`, it will unsubscribe from the source, then it will **re-subscribe** to it.

`retryWhen(fn)` maintains an inner subscription, which is the result of the observable provided with the function `fn`. The `fn`'s single argument is an **errors subject** that will push values every time an error occurs.

So, if you have

```js
retryWhen(subjectErrors => subjectErrors.pipe(a(), b()))
```

is essentially the same as:

```js
const subjectErrors = new Subject();
subjectErrors.pipe(a(), b()).subscriber(innerSubscriber);
```

An `innerSubscriber` is used inside `retryWhen` too, and its main role is to inform when a value(`next notification`) arrives.

When this happens, the source will be **re-subscribed**. In this case, the source is an observable that makes an http request, and when an error occurs, it will send an `error` notification; if the request is successful, it will emit a `next` notification, followed by a `complete` notification.

`take(5)` from `retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(5)))` means that when 5 attempts are reached, the `innerSubscriber`(that one from above) will emit a `complete` notification.

Then you have `last`, which has **no default value**. This means that when it receives a `complete` notification, without receiving any `next` notifications before, it will emit an error(default behavior).

Then the error is caught by `catchError()` in your effect. So this should explain why this approach works.

> What is weird is, that when the http-interceptor uses the operator retry rather than retryWhen it works just fine.

This is something I couldn't explain why because, using the information from the previous section, it should work fine, the created streams should be identical.

If you have

```js
load () {
 return this.http.get(...);
}
```

and assuming that interceptor is the only one you're using, in

```js
mergeMap(() =>
  this.globalStatsService.load().pipe(
    map(stats =>
      globalStatsActions.loaded({
        latestStats: stats
      })
    ),
    catchError(() => of(globalStatsActions.loadFailed())) // not being called using the http-interceptor
  )
)
```

`this.globalStatsService.load()` should be the same as

```js
of(request).pipe(
  concatMap(
    req => new Observable(s => { /* making the request.. */ }).pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(5))),
      last(),
    )
  )
)
```

which should be the same as with what happens in the previous section.

So, if I'm not missing anything, the `catchError` should be reached.

If not, it could mean that you either have some other `catchError` or `last` has received a value and thus it does not throw an error.

Does it log something in this case?

```js
    // here the NGRX failure action is not being triggered after five failing requests
    return httpHandler.handle(nextRequest).pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(5))),
      tap(console.log), 
      last()
    );
```

### Edit

As can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L322), the observable in which the request happens will send through its subscriber an event which indicates that the request has been dispatched.

With this in mind, you could use the `filter` operator:

```js
return httpHandler.handle(nextRequest).pipe(
  filter(ev => ev.type !== 0),
  retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(5))),
  last()
);
```

Comment: +1 for the explanations about things. I added the `tap(console.log)` it runs `console.log` on each failing request.. W/ and w/o `last()`. The value is `{ type: 0 }`.
I can assure you that their is truly no other `catchError` (or whatever might interfere) for this specific effect.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about it! Makes sense now. [Source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L322). It's an event that indicates that the request has been 'dispatched'. You could add `filter(e => e.type !== 0)` before the `retryWhen`. Let me know if that works

Comment: Hah! That's it indeed. Please add it to your answer and I will mark it as the solution :)

Cheers